# how can we query prospect based on their field value?

Tags: api, pardot

I want to get a prospect list from Pardot using its API and only those prospects that have some field's value according to some rules.
For Example :
those prospects which have a website containing 'some string' and year_in_bussines > 3

Answer (score 0):

Your best option here would be to create a dynamic list with your search criteria, then use the API to query prospects on your list with the query argument `list_id`.

Do keep in mind, dynamic lists are not updated instantly as prospects match/unmatch the criteria, there can be a delay.